# Symlinks corruption in iOS custom framework

Tags: ios, xcode, symlink, ios-frameworks

I'm currently working on the already developed iOS project. In this project  custom framework is used which is giving me error `'abcLib/abcLib.h' file not found`.

When I had a look at framework in the `Finder`, **I found that the symlinks are broken** and because of which I'm not able to include the `Header files` in project which leads to file not found error.

Following image shows the custom framework structure:
[image]

I also got the framework in .zip format from one of my colleague (who probably has a windows machine) and tried to integrate it again but issue still persist. 
Is there a way by which I can get the framework with no broken symlinks or a way to recreate the broken symlinks.

Or that I'll need the code that created the framework

***Note: I don't have the Project used to create the framework.***

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can recreate the symlinks using [this script](https://gist.github.com/spawnrider/6088294). I used it a couple times, it works fine.

Edit :

First delete all broken symlinks.

Then you can recreate them using this command :

```
ln -s {path_to_folder_or_file} {name_of_symlink}
```

So you will need in `myFramework.framework/Versions/` :

- The symlink `Current` that points to `A`

And in `myFramework.framework/` :

- The symlink `Headers` that points to `/Versions/Current/Headers`
- The symlink `Resources` that points to `/Versions/Current/Resources` **if you have one**
- The symlink `myFramework` that points to `/Versions/Current/myFramework`

Comment: @ebluehands: Thanks for your response and your answer does help me to recreate the broken symlinks. But still their is one issue. If you look at the path PcfLib.framework/Versions/A in that PcfLib file exist which is as far as I know a Static Library / Fat binary which also seems to be corrupted. Is there a way to recreate that too. Thanks!

Comment: @ebluehands: Getting Error - framework not found PcfLib.


clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: The error suggests that the framework can't be found, not corrupted. When you added the framework to your project, did you check the box "copy items if needed" ? Make sure that your framework is indeed copied in your project and that it is present in `Build Phase -> Link Binary With Libraries`.
But **if** the binary is corrupted, I'm afraid you can't fix it unless you have the code to rebuild it.

Comment: @ebluehands: Yes while adding framework to the project I checked the box "copy items if needed". and also the framework is present in 'Build Phase -> Link Binary With Libraries'. Also tried setting the 'Framework Search Paths', but all helpless :(